# Randomize a tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

How do I randomize all the weights of some given model in Tensorflow ?

Let's say I have a subclassed Keras model, or some model obtained through the functional API.

I want to randomize the weights of that object *without creating a new one*

Is there a way to do that ? Like some kind of `model.randomize` ?

Comment: why nd what do u mean by "randomize weights"?

Comment: I don't understand your question: I want to draw the weights anew, randomly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at source code, method `build` re-initializes the weights. So you may do:

```
for layer in model.layers:
    layer.build(layer.input_shape)
```

But why not creating new object of the same class?

Comment: I'll try this, thanks, this is because I want to test what happens when the weights of this particular model are changed, in the context of it being embedded as part of another model